# how to use python to parse a html that is in txt format?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am trying to parse a txt, example as below link.
The txt, however, is in the form of html. I am trying to get "COMPANY CONFORMED NAME" which located at the top of the file, and my function should return "Monocle Acquisition Corp".
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1754170/0001571049-19-000004.txt

I have tried below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1754170/0001571049-19-000004.txt'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html")
```

However, "soup" does not contain "COMPANY CONFORMED NAME" at all.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems like this document contains some HTML, but the part you are interested in is not HTML. You cannot use Beautiful Soup to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are looking for is not in an HTML structure so Beautiful Soup is not the best tool. The correct and fast way of searching for this data is just using a simple Regular Expression like this:

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1754170/0001571049-19-000004.txt'
r = requests.get(url)
text_string = r.content.decode()

name_re = re.compile("COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:[\\t]*(.+)\n")

match = name_re.search(text_string).group(1)
print(match)
```

Answer (score 1):

the part you look like is inside a huge tag `<SEC-HEADER>`

you can get the whole section by using `soup.find('sec-header')`
but you will need to parse the section manually, something like this works, but it's some dirty job :

(view it in replit : https://repl.it/@gui3/stackoverflow-parsing-html)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1754170/0001571049-19-000004.txt'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html")

header = soup.find('sec-header').text

company_name = None

for line in header.split('\n'):
    split = line.split(':')
    if len(split) > 1 :
        key = split[0]
        value = split[1]
        if key.strip() == 'COMPANY CONFORMED NAME':
            company_name = value.strip()
            break

print(company_name)
```

*There may be some library able to parse this data better than this code*